# Changing binary file to readable text file

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a program that creates a file that stores text like this:

```
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

now I need to convert this file to this:

```
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

I know this is possible because I use a simple windows program to make the conversion. I want to be able to make the conversion on the Linux command line.

Comment: Not enough information is given to answer the question. *Specifically* what format is the file in -- what program did you use to create it?

Comment: Was the 'simple conversion program' written by the same people who wrote the application creating the files?  It probably knows the structure of the binary file and is therefore able to read it and then export a text file.  Not knowing the structure can make it near impossible to write something that can read/convert it, since a binary file can pretty much be anything in any layout.

Comment: if i do a cat filename, or od -c filename i can read some of the text but its not in the correct format.

Comment: i do not know what format the file is in, and the program is custom so its not freely available.

Comment: Any chance of putting a before and after example on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or something?  We have no idea how the file is encoded or what is going on with the "decoder" program...

Comment: Files are sequences of bytes, both binary and ASCII files. It depends on how the data was encoded when you want to convert it to another encoding. These [mime-types](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Mime-type) don't help much.

Answer (score 0):

use [`strings`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?strings)? Assuming there's plaintext in there somewhere, that will at least give you something to look at.

Comment: if i do a cat filename, or od -c filename i can read some of the text but its not in the correct format.

Comment: @reyes You are not giving enough information to answer this question. Save the file content to a pastebin. Then show a before and after of the windows conversion so we can see the format. Otherwise, this question will not be answered effectively.